# Hybrid search with SharePoint 2010

Tags: search, office-365, hybrid

Please help me with the approach, I will explain you requirement

We have SP2010 environment and now we want to migrate to Office 365. Our requirement are

1. Once site collections are migrated to O365 users should be redirected to O365 even if he enters SP2010 URL.
2. Search result on SP2010 should include results from O365.

Regards

Prasad Tandel

Comment: I am looking at Hybrid scenario now and from what I see it is just 2013/2016 so not sure if No.2 is possible. With No.1 it would depend on your infrastructure. If you have some good load balancing that would be right place to place redirection (pretty easy on Netscaler) alternatively you can put redirection on the IIS server. https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 you would address this with your network team. You could easily provision an IIS server with redirects.

For #2, if you plan to keep your on-prem SharePoint 2010 farm, you cannot do hybrid, but you could easily provision a single SharePoint 2013 or 2016 box and only use it for hybrid search. In fact, you could use it to crawl SharePoint 2010 and push the index to Office 365. (and remove the 2010 Search Service) Configure the Search connection to the 2013/2016 box and all your results can come from Office 365.

Comment: Thank, we have proposed same to client

Comment: Do you have any reference document for same ??

Comment: For which part? #2?

Comment: Yes Matthew for #2

Comment: This can get you started: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx